# X-editable and angularjs directive, not binding for server data

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, x-editable

I am trying to build a user entry form with x-editable and angularjs. While prototyping, everything seems to be okay when binding to the static data. The controls are stopped binding when the data is fetched from server(as shown in the screenshot attached) I have extracted a fiddler the issue can be reproduced here

http://jsfiddle.net/2p93vy8x/

The directive as follows

```
 myApp.directive('xeditable', function($timeout) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: "ngModel",
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            attrs.$observe('pk', function(value){
                var pk = value;
                attrs.$observe('xeditableSource', function(source){
                    if(!source) {source=null; value=null;}
                    else {value=scope.languageIdx;}
                    var loadXeditable = function() {
                        element.editable({
                            display: function(value, srcData) {
                                ngModel.$setViewValue(value);
                                scope.$apply();

                            },
                            mode:'popup',
                            pk: pk,
                            url: scope.url,
                            source:source,
                            value:value
                        });   
                    }; 
                    $timeout(function() {
                        loadXeditable();
                    }, 10);   
                });       
            });
        }    };
```

});

Any help on this is greatly appreciated,

[image]

Comment: Not real familiar with x-editable, but you may need to implement the "success" method in addition to "display"

Answer (score 1):

That is because the data fetched from the server arrives a bit later after your control has been initialized, so it doesn't know the new values.

To fix that, you need to watch the model changes and update your control:

```
scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function(val) {
  console.log(attrs.ngModel + ' is now', val)
  // I don't know how x-editable works, but you need to update it here.
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you might want to try angular-xeditable module as a more elegant approach.  I've set up a working example in plunkr for your convenience [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/9zSYp5G4rT5zO41uc6Iv).

**Html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <link data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.3.1" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link data-require="xeditable@*" data-semver="0.1.8" rel="stylesheet" href="http://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/dist/js/xeditable.js" />

  <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.13/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.13"></script>
  <script data-require="xeditable@*" data-semver="0.1.8" src="http://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/dist/js/xeditable.js"></script>

  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div ng-controller="ValidateRemoteCtrl" ng-init="checkName(user.login)">
    <p>
      Editable:
      <a href="#" editable-text="user.login" onbeforesave="checkName($data)">
        {{ user.login}} 
      </a>,
      <a href="#" editable-text="user.id">
        {{ user.id}} 
      </a>
    </p>

    <p>user: {{user.login}}</p>
    <p>id: {{user.id}}</p>
    <p>public repos: {{user.public_repos}}</p>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

**Js**

```
var app = angular.module('app', ["xeditable"]);

app.controller('ValidateRemoteCtrl', function($scope, $http, $q) {
  $scope.user = {
    login: 'ariellephan'
  };

  $scope.checkName = function(data) {
    $http.get("https://api.github.com/users/" + data).success(function(res) {
      $scope.user = res;
    }).error(function(e) {
      d.reject('Server error!');
    });

  };
});
```